# Drop down menu gettind displayed at the back of youtube video

Tags: css

I am having a visibility problem in my code. I have this a drop down menu which drops down on a youtube video. What happens is that the menu is displayed at the back of youtube video instead of getting displayed in the front. Please help. Thanks
[image]

Here is the code for my menu,

```
<div style="margin-top:-60px;padding-bottom:20px;position:relative;overflow:visible;">

<div class='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/starthere'><span>Start Here</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/starthere'><span>New To The Site? Start Here</span></a></li>
         <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/about'><span>About</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/Contact'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/hello-world/'><span>What Is Finance Yoga?</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/SaveMoney'><span>Save Money</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/SaveMoney'><span>Ways To Save</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/category/ways-to-save/moving/'><span>Moving</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/category/ways-to-save/coupons-and-cash-back/'><span>Coupons & Cash Back</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/category/ways-to-save/moving/'><span>Moving</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/makemoney '><span>Make Money</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/category/make-extra-money/series-make-quick-money/'><span>Series - Make Quick Money</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/how-to-make-money-with-a-blog/'><span>Make Money Blogging</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/onlinebanking'><span>Online Banking</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/onlinebanking'><span>Online Banking</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/category/checking-accounts/'><span>Best Checking Accounts</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/onlinebanking'><span>Online Banking</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Finance Tools</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='http://financeyoga.com/AmazonDeals'><span>Amazon Deals</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='href="http://www.amazonwireless.com/b/684177011/?_encoding=UTF8&tag=finayoga-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325'><span>Amazon Wireless</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://www.amazon.com/b?_encoding=UTF8&site-redirect=&node=281407&tag=finayoga-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325'><span>Electronics</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='http://www.amazon.com/b?_encoding=UTF8&site-redirect=&node=4736&tag=finayoga-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325'><span>Books</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00067L6TQ" rel="nofollow noreferrer"http://www.amazon.com/b?_encoding=UTF8&site-redirect=&node=229534&tag=finayoga-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325'><span>Software</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='href="http://www.amazon.com/b?_encoding=UTF8&site-redirect=&node=195209011&tag=finayoga-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325'><span>Music</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='href="http://www.amazon.com/b?_encoding=UTF8&site-redirect=&node=51569011&tag=finayoga-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325'><span>Apparel & Accessories</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem:** You have a CSS based drop-down menu in your navigation and a flash element near it the menus may get “hidden” behind the flash object.

**The Solution:** Set the z-index of the div holding the flash to 1 and the z-index of the div holding the nav to 2. (`z-index:1;` and `z-index:2;`)
In the flash element:
Look for the flash `<object>` tag and add the following code:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

You’ll want to insert this code right below the `<param name=”quality” value=”high”>` tag and include the code `wmode=”transparent”` in the flash `<embed>` tag.

Try it and good luck!

Original text found at http://wphacks.com/fixing-css-drop-down-menus-hiding-behind-flash-objects/

Comment: `value = high` or `value = transparent`? Thanks

Comment: An example `<iframe width=”640″ height=”480″ src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/rLVCjnEGrqQ?wmode=transparent” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen wmode=”transparent”></iframe>`

Value should be high, and wmode transparent.. 
This works on iframe too.

Comment: you can skip the param name, unless it's obvious where to add it.. It's not always in the existing code, and YouTube takes care of most of it anyway.